# Effect of adding/removing layers in CNN

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I wanted to know about how adding layers or removing layers in a convolutional neural network affects the results produced. My problem specifically deals with detection of lips, something like this https://img-s3.onedio.com/id-57dc3cd17669c0cf0e4e2705/rev-0/raw/s-4909b77cbbb875d94fea9406a207936f767dc5de.jpg. (I use this CNN network in a DCGAN).
I have an average GPU, which is taking a lot of time to train the model. I currently have 4 layers in my CNN network, and wanted to know how removing one layer may affect the results and training time of the model. I understand that to correctly answer this question, a lot more details are needed. I am just looking for a broad answer, primarily focusing on what role a single layer plays, and how can reducing them affect the model.